# Is there a way to have Git automatically detach when switching to a commit?

Tags: git

When switching to a specific commit with `git checkout <commit-hash>`, git would automatically enter detached-head mode. If you use `git switch <commit-hash>`, it just fails and asks you to provide the `--detach` flag. Is there any way to get the behaviour of `git checkout` while using `git switch`?

(When running `git switch <branch-name>` I don't want to detach, so I can't just unconditionally add the `--detach` flag.)

Comment: So why don't you use `git checkout <commit-hash>` if that's what you want to do?

Comment: I'm used to using the same command for switching to a branch and switching to a commit. Having to always remember to use a different command for commits is a hassle.

Comment: If `git switch` is a hassle, just use `git checkout` all the time, that seems to be what you want. (That's what I still always use, for what it's worth, I have not adopted switch.)

Answer (score 0):

[`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) behaves exactly as you have described:

- `git checkout branch` switches the branch
- `git checkout hashofacommit` switches to detached HEAD state
- `git checkout --detach branch` and `git checkout branch^{}` detach HEAD for the last commit of this branch